# ionic v2 menu: content inside <ion-nav> is not rendered

Tags: ionic-framework, menu

Can someone tell me why this does not work (no error is thrown, but nothing is rendered either)

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-menu [content]="menu" type="push">
    'some content...''
  </ion-menu>

  <ion-nav #menu [root]="HomePage">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>Toggle Menu</button>
    'some content...''
  </ion-nav>
</ion-content>
```

The following renders everything correctly, but the menu does not behave as expected (it does not "push" the content aside, but slides in underneath it)

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-menu [content]="menu" type="push">
    'some content...''
  </ion-menu>

  <ion-nav #menu [root]="HomePage"></ion-nav>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>Toggle Menu</button>
    'some content...''
</ion-content>
```

I want my menu to push the page content aside when toggled...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>


<ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons end>
    <button (click)="dismissModal()">Cancel</button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

The code above is not rendered anymore in a modal window, changing to ion-toolbar and adding own 'Cancel-button' instead of default back-button fixes the problem though.